# Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. React Native - Expo Camera

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

[This warning appears to me when I capture several images by expo camera in a short time which is necessary for my project, how can I get rid of this warning as it prevents the camera from taking pictures after a while ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RawMw.jpg)

```
const takePicture = async () => {
if (cameraRef.current) {
  const options = {quality: 0.1, base64: true, skipProcessing: true};
  const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
  Camera.Constants.AutoFocus.on
  const source = data.uri;
  const actions = [{resize:{width : 320}}]
  const saveOptions = {compress:0.2,base64:true}
  const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(source,actions,saveOptions)
  if (source) {
    setIsPreview(true);  
    Send_Img(manipResult.base64);
    setInterval(() => {
    takePicture()},500);
  }
}
```

};

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't your setInterval at the bottom cause the code to be run infinitely?

Comment: yes, but this warning appears just after 20-30 secs from running the code, my project is a self-driving car using Opencv so I need to send these images to the algorithm to make the car decide which direction to go.

Comment: I tried to use setTimeout instead of setInterval and the warning disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I used setTimeout instead of setInterval and it is done